# document microservice built using akka-http with swagger

Tags: scala, swagger, microservices, akka-http

I am trying to build microservices with design first approach and using akka-http(scala) 2.4.1. For the design-first, IMHO, swagger is widely used. I couldn't find any boilerplate implementation as to how swagger works with akka-http.

How could I proceed?

I found a thread https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16591 which talks about this to some extent, but couldn't find a conclusion / approach to take.

Also, there seems to be one not maintained version of a library https://github.com/Tecsisa/akka-http-swagger

In the swagger community, found a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/swagger-swaggersocket/microservice/swagger-swaggersocket/Ob4fy0KK9jw/qSQ5yI3-DAAJ) indicating to use [swagger-inflector](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-inflector) for ensuring the implementation is adhering to the swagger spec developed, but that seems to blend well with java and not with scala.

Comment: I've had extensive experience with Swagger (several projects). Couple points: 1) you can't automatically create swagger description for akka-http/spray routes. 2) swagger is very buggy. 3) project is led by lazy dude who hates it. 4) bug reports are either silently closed or open for a year or maintainer responds with "it works for me" comments. I highly recommend avoiding this pile of s..software.

Comment: Thank you @ruslan for your feedback. In your point 2, did you mean Swagger at large OR akka-http-swagger, kindly clarify?

Comment: @ruslan Do you have examples of bug reports not handled properly?

Comment: @wing328 Of course. I'm pretty sure `ApiImplicitParams` and missing body param are still broken (last time I checked was in Sep). Here are issues I reported: https://goo.gl/vJJ7fP The guy who sabotages the project is Ron `webron`.